# JPA - Repeated column in mapping for entity @OneToOne

Tags: jpa

I have two simple tables: Users and User_Roles.
In both tables i have a field `email` and i want load User_Roles from UserEntity, the query should be:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Users u, User_Roles ur
 WHERE u.email = ur.email;
```

When i try to "link" the email field i get the error "Repeated column in mapping for entity: UserEntity column: email".

I've tried to add any kind of combination (mappedBy, refColumn etc) but the error is even the same...

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String email;
    private UserRolesEntity roles;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "email")
    public UserRolesEntity getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }
    public void setRoles(UserRolesEntity roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }
}
```

User_Roles

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRolesEntity {

    private long id;
    private String email;
    private String role;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_role_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Basic
    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }
    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a 1-1 relation, so need a FK in the UserRolesEntity class. You cannot use a STRING field as a ForeignKey to something that has an identity of type LONG!!!

Comment: I suspected a thing like this.... i did hever used FK annotation before.... can you please tell me how i will need to modify UserRolesEntity? Next on it, i will studi your solution for the future... thanks a lot...

Comment: Modify ? You DELETE @JoinColumn(name = "email") from the other class. 1-1 relations are in any JPA docs

Comment: But if i delete the @JoinColumn JPA how now that the mapping must be done by email field? I've tried to remove this annotation but i get errors...

Comment: You CANNOT do a mapping by an email field. It is not the identity of the other object. JPA supports object-oriented design; modelling via email is not that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link the User_Roles and User, you should keep the User's primary key in User_Roles. So you would better modify your User_Roles table like this:

```
long user_role_id
long user
String role
```

Then your User_Roles class would be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_roles")
public class UserRolesEntity {

private long id;
private User user;
private String role;

@Id
@Column(name = "user_role_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToOne
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Basic
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
}
```

If you want get the user email from user_role, you can do like this: `userRole.getUser().getEmail()`

And then the User class would be:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private long id;
private String email;
private UserRolesEntity roles;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy="user")
public UserRolesEntity getRoles() {
    return roles;
}
public void setRoles(UserRolesEntity roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```